# Hide specific filetypes in finder

Tags: finder, file

SWIM works on a lot of different Ableton Live projects and has more than 25,000 '.asd'-files on their computer. On macOS dot-files are hidden by default in finder, does anyone know if it's possible to hide files in finder depending on their extension/filetype?

Answer (score 2):

With a huge help from nohillside, here's a quick fix:

Remember to test run on a test folder.

```
find ~/Documents -name '*.asd' >> ~/Desktop/logHiddenASDfiles.txt
find ~/Documents -name '*.asd' -exec chflags hidden '{}' \;
```

First command uses `>>` to not to override existing logs, it always appends content to the file.

To undo the hidden flags,

```
find ~/Documents -name '*.asd' -exec chflags nohidden '{}' \;
```

The log file might not be of immediate use since you might move or delete some files. If you use the older file for unhiding the files, some of them might throw errors.

Comment: What is the purpose of the log file? The files don't get removed and can easily be found again (as you show as well), why log them? You don't use the log file for any changes anyway.

Comment: uhh nothing apparently.. I used it for a dry run. Also best to remember such stuff,, I have made so many modifications that I'm afraid I might forget. Imagine suddenly some ghost is taking up Gigs of space

Comment: Dry run? `find ~/Documents -name '*.asd' -exec echo chflags hidden '{}' \;` :-)